# Preview Templates of Asp.Net 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I just installed VS2015 and I'm wondering if I should use the Asp.Net 5 preview template (this is the only option I currently have in VS2015) for my new website. Does anyone know if this preview is some sort of a beta version which might be unstable? If not, why is this version called a preview version?
I didn't find much information about this preview thing in Google so I'll be happy to get some relevant information or links to explanations about this preview version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET 5 is still in beta, and is not yet released as a finished product nor recommended for production applications.  It's marked as preview because of this, as it may (and will) continue to change how it does things until it reaches the RTM version.

If you are happy with the above, and want to tinker around, while understanding that updates in the coming months may break your code, then go for it!  If you'd rather only write your code once and not have it break with updates, then stick with the previous ASP.NET project types like MVC 5.

Here's the [roadmap/schedule for ASP.NET 5](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) which notes that RTM is expected to be available in Q1 2016.